# How to MODIFY file from the QtCreator wizard

Tags: qt-creator, wizard

I have found many similar Q&A here, but all end up with suggestion of modifying .pro template in the project wizard (e.g. it can be used only when the project is being initially created). My task is bit different and I wonder if/how it can be achieved:

I want to have a wizard (e.g. based on standard C++ *new class* wizard), which adds Version object class **into existing C++ project**. (It will supply various values like major and minor version number based on git commits and labels.)

I am almost done with the task, I do even have modified C++ new class wizard, which copies all necessary modified files from templates, still there is one thing remaining. I need to add (or append) following two lines "somewhere" into **existing** .pro file.

```
RAW_VERSION = $$system($$quote(git describe --tags --long --match [vV][0-9]*))
QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES += Version/Version.h.in
```

Can this be achieved by some JSON wizard feature and if so, what should the related construct look like?

Comment: Sounds a bit like you could just use a [snippet](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html#editing-code-snippets) to begin with?

Comment: There is no way to do this from a JSON wizard directly. You might want to take a look how it is done for the "Add library" context menu item on qmake projects: [QmakeManager::addLibraryImpl](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/src/plugins/qmakeprojectmanager/qmakeprojectmanager.cpp#n132)

Comment: @E4z9 Yes, I understand both concepts, code snippets and wizards in general. The thing is, that i need to do both inserting files (Version.cpp and Version.h), to make it bit more difficult even into subdirectory Version to keep source tree clear, and modify Project.pro.

Comment: Phew, need to do it hard way because of some stupid edit/comment lenght limits. So in two parts: 1/3 @E4z9 Yes, I understand both concepts, code snippets and wizards in general. The thing is, that i need to do both inserting files (Version.cpp and Version.h), to make it bit more difficult even into subdirectory Version to keep source tree clear, and modify Project.pro, preferably in one simple select-and-click. I do understand the linked C++ code, however my question is how can this (or similar) C++ code be activated from the JSON wizard?

Comment: 2/3 @E4z9 Could you be more specific about a) where to place code (or compiled binary) achieving the task and b) how to activate it from JSON code? Moreover I have seen some JS:<code> constructs in some wizards, but did not so far found any man page about it.

Comment: 3/3 @E4z9Could there be a way to open-modify-save file (e.g. Project.pro) through the javascript? Seeing many many questions about simple .pro file modification automations (often e.g. to add C++11 features) I feel great requirement for some "modify .pro file" tool on JSON wizard in general - so I would eventually offer sharing of my own solution would I get enough info to develop it.